# IEEE Access License on Arxiv

Tags: copyright, arxiv, ieee

I would like to submit an article to IEEE Access. As per their requirements, I need to add a license statement on my corresponding ArXiv upload, which will look like this:

> IEEE copyright notice. © 2020 IEEE. Personal use of this material is
>   permitted. Permission from IEEE must be obtained for all other uses,
>   in any current or future media, including reprinting/republishing this
>   material for advertising or promotional purposes, creating new
>   collective works, for resale or redistribution to servers or lists, or
>   reuse of any copyrighted

My question is: Which copyright do I have to select on ArXiv?
They offer the following options:

- arXiv.org perpetual, non-exclusive license to distribute this article
  (Minimal rights required by arXiv.org)
- Creative Commons Attribution
  license (CC BY 4.0)
- Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike license
  (CC BY-SA 4.0)
- Creative Commons Attribution-Noncommercial-ShareAlike
  license (CC BY-NC-SA 4.0)
- Creative Commons Public Domain Declaration
  (CC0 1.0)
- None of the above licenses apply

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only the last option applies.

Once you assign all rights to the IEEE (or anyone), then you no longer have the right to license the work yourself.

And the IEEE statements is pretty clear that they retain almost all rights. It doesn't mean that they might not give a more permissive license at some point, but you no longer have that ability.

Comment: This. In addition, from what you're shown here it's not clear that you are allowed to put it on arXiv at all.

Comment: @Flyto, perhaps you are correct, but my interpretation was that IEEE wanted it put up, but with their copyright notice.

Comment: Ah, you may be right.