# ArXiv license to choose for a paper to be published in IEEE Transactions on Neural Networks and Learning Systems?

Tags: copyright, arxiv, ieee, license

I´ve seen similar questions to mine (as [Which license should be chosen in arXiv for a paper to be published in IEEE TPDS?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/107477/which-license-should-be-chosen-in-arxiv-for-a-paper-to-be-published-in-ieee-tpds) or [IEEE Access License on Arxiv](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/143788/ieee-access-license-on-arxiv)
) but answers did not completely solve my doubts.

I will upload a paper for reviewing at [IEEE Transactions on Neural Networks and Learning Systems](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/RecentIssue.jsp?punumber=5962385) and I would also like to upload the pre-print to arXiv.

I don't know which license of the ones arXiv offers (https://arxiv.org/help/license) should be selected. It looks like, in the past, arXiv allowed to select than none of those licenses is the right one, so IEEE recommended that. Anyway, that is not possible nowadays and one type of license of the previous link must be selected ([it should be explained here, but I'm afraid it is not](https://journals.ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/become-an-ieee-journal-author/publishing-ethics/guidelines-and-policies/post-publication-policies/)).

Can someone help me to avoid any troubles selecting an incorrect license? (I contacted the journal two weeks ago but they've not answered at this moment).

Thank you for your help!

Comment: As mentioned in the [accepted answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/107648) to [Which license should be chosen in arXiv for a paper to be published in IEEE TPDS?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/107477), you need to go for the arXiv.org license. IEEE also has some other rules (like placing copyright notices) about posting your preprint and the accepted article to arXiv, which you can find on the page titled [Post-Publication Policies](https://journals.ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/become-an-ieee-journal-author/publishing-ethics/guidelines-and-policies/post-publication-policies/).

Comment: @TheAmplitwist Thanks! Regarding notices, IEEE general site for publication policies(https://journals.ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/become-an-ieee-journal-author/publishing-ethics/guidelines-and-policies/post-publication-policies/) says that pre-print must carry the message: “This work has been submitted to the IEEE for possible ....”. Nevertheless, the specific journal (https://pspb.ieee.org/images/files/files/opsmanual.pdf, page 88) states a different message ("© 20xx IEEE. Personal use of this material is permitted. Permission..."), which one should I go with?

Comment: Go with the first message for your preprint. The second message should be used *after* your article has been accepted for publication. These details are present in the [Post-Publication Policies](https://journals.ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/become-an-ieee-journal-author/publishing-ethics/guidelines-and-policies/post-publication-policies/) page, but you understandably might have missed them. Would you prefer I turn my comments into an answer?

Comment: @TheAmplitwist Thanks again. I'm probably getting fussy: I plan to submit the paper first to IEEE and then to arXiv, so I guess the following applies (from previous pdf): "In any preprint version archived by the author after submission, IEEE requires that IEEE will be credited as copyright holder...", so I suppose that I should go with the message “© 20xx IEEE. Personal use of this material is permitted. Permission from IEEE must be obtained for all other uses, in any current or future media...”, which directly given them the copyright (I am probably wrecking my head more than it's necessary).

Comment: No problem! Better to be safe than sorry. :) My understanding is that you need to place that message only *after* copyright has been transferred to IEEE. If I'm not mistaken, you sign the copyright transfer agreement only after the acceptance of the article, and not before. So, the message "© 20xx IEEE. Personal use of this material..." doesn't seem to be applicable when you've not yet transferred copyright.

Comment: To corroborate, the PDF you linked says, "...the
following copyright notice must be displayed on the initial screen
displaying **IEEE-copyrighted material**", so it doesn't need to be displayed until you've transferred copyright to IEEE.

Comment: (I'll have to turn in for the day, so I'll be unable to check up on any replies for several hours. All the best, in any case!)

Comment: @TheAmplitwist Thank you again. I find it conflicting, I still think that the message “© 20xx IEEE. Personal use of this material is permitted...” is the better one cause in the pdf they say that once the work've submitted to IEEE, they already have the copyright: "**In any preprint version archived by the author after submission, IEEE requires that IEEE will be credited as copyright holder**. Upon publication of the work, authors are asked to include the article’s Digital Object Identifier (DOI)."

Comment: In Post-Publication Policies, they state that "The preprint is the article in the form prior to submission to IEEE", so I assume that's why they go with the other message. In any case, I guess that I will have no problems with any of them. Again, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the default license (the arxiv.org license). It's the most restrictive one they offer.

The ieee page you link is exceedingly clear that posting on arxiv is allowed, with the only restriction that you have to update the arxiv with the DOI once published.